# MySQL Как заполнить пустые ячейки одной таблицы значениями другой?

Tags: mysql

Доброго времени суток.
Столкнулся с вот какой проблемой:
Существует таблица oc_product_desctiption ~3К записей, из них в 96 поле meta_title пустое.
Рядом с ней таблица oc_product_old в которой это поле пустое только у 10 записей.
Каким образом можно заполнить пустые поля первой таблицы полями второй(с совпадением по полю product_id)?
Пытался подобным образом:

```
SELECT * FROM oc_product_description AS a WHERE meta_title = ""
UPDATE * FROM oc_product_description_old AS b WHERE b.product_id = a.product_id;
```

Селект отрабатывает, на апдейте ошибка, у меня довольно скудные знания в этой области, очень надеюсь на помощь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение в лоб:

```
UPDATE oc_product_description a
SET a.meta_title = (
  SELECT meta_title 
  FROM oc_product_description_old b
  WHERE b.product_id = a.product_id)
WHERE a.meta_title = '';
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное!

Answer (score 0):

А почему не просто

```
UPDATE oc_product_description a, oc_product_description_old b
SET a.meta_title = b.meta_title
WHERE a.product_id = b.product_id AND a.meta_title = ''
```